# Manipulating mongodb's bson.D output format

Tags: json, mongodb, go, mongodb-query, bson

Im using FindOne to query one row of data (single document):

package main

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/fatih/color" 
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func mongoDbFindOne(key, value string) bson.D {
    var result bson.D
    _ = Collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.D{{key, value}}).Decode(&result)
    color.Green("[+] Found: %+v\n", result)
    return result
}
```

And this a small part of how the result is shown:

```
[
    {
        "Key": "_id",
        "Value": "1600540844649"
    },
    {
        "Key": "hostname",
        "Value": "DESKTOP-xxxxxx"
    },
    {
        "Key": "cmdLine",
        "Value": []
    },
    {
        "Key": "pid",
        "Value": 4816
    }
]
```

But this how i want it to be:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1600540844649"
    },
    {
        "hostname": "DESKTOP-xxxxxx"
    },
    {
        "cmdLine": []
    },
    {
        "pid": 4816
    }
]
```

Or:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1600540844649",
        "hostname": "DESKTOP-xxxxxx",
        "cmdLine": [],
        "pid": 4816,
    }
]
```

What should i do? I have searched through SO and google but no luck. Should i use `struct` or creating any objects? I also searched for saving/converting bson to json but there is solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself:
Using `bson.M` instead of `bson.D` solved my issue:

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/fatih/color" 
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func mongoDbFindOne(key, value string) bson.M {
    var result bson.M
    _ = Collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{key:value}).Decode(&result)
    color.Green("[+] Found: %+v\n", result)
    return result
}
```